# How to strip leading character from a set of characters in a string?

Tags: c, string, char

I need to strip a set of characters from a string in C.

Say `str = "01 "`, then:

1. `"112345"` the output should be `"2345"`
2. `"0 78abc"` the output should be `"78abc"`
3. `"   7777"` the output should be `"7777"`

I hope you understand with the help of the examples.

function format to be:

```
char* StripLeadingChars(char* str, char* originalString)
```

EDIT:
I am sorry for not elaborating the code. I have tried coding it, and below is my code.

```
char* StripLeadingChars(char* str, char* originalString)
{
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        for(int j=0,k=0;j<=strlen(originalString);j++)
        {
            if(originalString[j]!=str[i])
                originalString[k++] = originalString[j];
        }
    }
    return originalString;
}
```

But this code strips all the characters of str present in originalString as below.

`str = "01 "`

`originalString="11230 45"`

output is `"2345"` whereas required output is `"230 45"`

Kindly help me in correcting my code. Thanks!

Comment: try something yourself, this is not a code writing service. People here will help you if you have some problem later while writing code, but try yourself first..

Comment: Shouldn't the 0 be removed in the expected output?

Comment: No, I need only the leading characters to be removed from the originalString.

Comment: Is it safe to *not* modify the `originalString` and just return a pointer to the correct starting point?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `strlen` in the end condition of `for` is inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge is handling all cases including your **test cases**, the **no-match** case and the **all-match** case. The following is an attempt at meeting all conditions. (NULL is returned if all characters match the `strip` characters) Comments are provided inline:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *StripLeadingChars (char *strip, char *string)
{
    int prefix = 0;     /* simple flag to test if in leading part of string */
    char *p = string;
    char *s = strip;

    if (!p) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: invalid string.\n", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }

    while (*p)                              /* for every character in string        */
    {
        while (*s)                          /* test each character in strip         */
        {
            while (*p == *s || *p == ' ') { /* string char matches strip or space   */
                p++;                        /* increment sting pointer              */
                prefix = 1;                 /* flag char matched                    */
            }
            s++;                            /* increment strip pointer              */
        }

        if (!prefix)                        /* break on first non-match of strip    */
            break;

        prefix = 0;                         /* reset toggle                         */
    }

    return (*p) ? p : NULL;                 /* if p valid, return p, else NULL      */
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 3 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input, usage: %s <strip> <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\nInput:\n\n  string : %s\n\n  strip  : %s\n\n", argv[2], argv[1]);

    printf ("\nstripped : %s\n\n", StripLeadingChars (argv[1], argv[2]));

    return 0;
}
```

**build/run:**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/stripld stripleading.c

./bin/stripld 01 112345

Input:

  string : 112345

  strip  : 01

stripped : 2345

./bin/stripld 01 "0 78abc"

Input:

  string : 0 78abc

  strip  : 01

stripped : 78abc

./bin/stripld 01 "  7777"

Input:

  string :   7777

  strip  : 01

stripped : 7777

./bin/stripld 01 "23 456"

Input:

  string : 23 456

  strip  : 01

stripped : 23 456

./bin/stripld 01 "00 11"

Input:

  string : 00 11

  strip  : 01

stripped : (null)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This indeed solves my problem. And I see where I was wrong in my code.

Comment: Glad I could help. It was an interesting problem over breakfast.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to complete this code:

```
char *stripLeadingChars(char* str, char* originalString) {
    while(originalString is not ended && first char of originalString belongs to str) {
        advance originalString;
    }
    return the string pointed by originalString;
}
```

For the test "belongs..." I suggest to use `strchr(str, first character of originalString)` which returns `NULL` (ie. false) if the character does not appear in `str`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a strlen() in loop - [here's why](http://www.cprogramming.com/tips/tip/dont-use-strlen-in-a-loop-condition).

You've tried something - that's ok. Here's a possible solution:

```
#include <string.h>

char* StripLeadingChars(char* str, char* orig) {
    while (strchr(str, *orig) != NULL) {
        ++orig;
    }
    return orig;
}
```

How it works: It checks whether a char in the beginning of `orig` is in `str` string literal. If so, it goes to next char of `orig`. If not, it stops checking and `orig` pointer is returned.

Comment: This approach does not strip leading spaces in the test cases `"0 78abc"` or `"  7777"` and returns `11` for the all-match case `"00 11"`. Adding a space to the `str` can correct the problem.

Comment: OP has a space in ``str``. There's no information that OP needs to handle leading spaces. So I think that you and i interpreted OPs problem differently and both solutions are valid.